# After selecting one radio button, I want the remaining buttons to become disabled

Tags: javascript, html, dom, radiobuttonlist

I am working on a pong game in java script where one can change the difficulty level using a set of radio buttons

```
<form action="">
        <input type="radio" name="level" value="8">Beginner<br> 
        <input type="radio" name="level" value="4">Intermediate<br>
        <input type="radio" name="level" value="2">Pro<br>        
      </form>
```

The level adjusts well on the first try but when someone clicks on another radio button the game court is affected and keeps on refreshing. I am using html 5  and set the fps to 60. What I wanted is after a new page refresh, when one selects one radio button, the remaining buttons should become disabled till the user refreshes the page. Is there a way to do this in vanilla js?

Comment: Can't you just read the value of the radiobuttons once and then ignore later changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over radio buttons collection and change their disabled status on change event. For example like this:

```js
var radios = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=level]'));

radios.forEach(function(radio) {
    radio.addEventListener('change', function() { 
        radios.forEach(function(r) {
            r.disabled = r !== radio;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="level" value="8">Beginner<br>
  <input type="radio" name="level" value="4">Intermediate<br>
  <input type="radio" name="level" value="2">Pro<br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. My presentation is tomorrow and I was stuck. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable them after one click then this should do..

```
 <form action="" name="formName">
            <input type="radio" name="level" value="8">Beginner<br> 
            <input type="radio" name="level" value="4">Intermediate<br>
            <input type="radio" name="level" value="2">Pro<br>        
          </form>
```

Onclick event

```
$("input:radio[name=level]").click(function(){
    var radios = document.formName.level;

        for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
          radios[i].disabled = true;
        } 
});
```

Here is a fiddle  [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/zm2yxj0x/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with plain javascript.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByName('level');

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
    buttons[i].onclick = function()
    {
     for(var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++)
        {
            if(j != i)
            {
                buttons[j].setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I would get rid of the `<form>` tag since it serves no purpose here.